# How should we tag questions that are a generic "why doesn't this work" type?

Tags: discussion, tagging

Quite a number of questions get asked that amount to "why doesn't this code work."  Some of these can and should be quickly clarified in the comments and closed as "a simple mistake" but many might reasonably be answered.

I wonder how these should be tagged if they are not about e.g. Plotting but about basic *Mathematica* programming itself.

- [programming](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/programming) should be reserved for *non-trival* programming as the tag description says
- [debugging](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/debugging) is for "Questions about debugging techniques" not "please help me fix my code."
- [code-review](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-review) is intended for review of style and improvement of already functioning code

What tag should we use so as not to dilute the content of tags such as those described above?

Comment: In [this related Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/749/245), it seems there was no consensus whether such "meta-tags" are  really needed. I don't really see a problem with a `beginners` tag - it does't have to be taken as having a negative connotation. But if tags are supposed to reflect subject matter, it won't work.

Comment: @Jens I disagree with the idea that a "broken code" tag (which I'm leaning toward) is a meta tag.  It is *not* like "beginner" or "basic" in that it *can* be objectively applied, and it *does* describe the *content* of the question.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I think what Jens is trying to say is that while "broken code" does describe the content, it is not useful as a _categorization_ term (i.e., one you would use to search). For instance, I have no idea what one would search for under [tag:broken-code]... Broken codes are usually localized, and as you say, the simple mistakes/doc lookups, etc. should be closed quickly. But for the ones worth keeping, there must be something  else that describes what's broken or what the OP's trying to do, that we could perhaps use to tag the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since no one has a suggestion I like better I'll propose my own:

[broken-code](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/broken-code)

I think this reasonably describes the general class of questions, is not disparaging, is objective, and should be reasonably easy to find (broken seem a pretty natural, and common, way to describe the issue.)

Comment: "Broken" somehow implies that the code was already working at some point, does it not?

Comment: @Yves That's a good point.  I don't know.  Actually now I'm curious about the word broken itself.

Comment: "Dysfunctional" perhaps also carries too much baggage ;-)

Comment: "Not-working" - could refer to code or poster, depending on who's doing the interpreting.

Comment: @Yves I [asked](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/122151/13162) about *broken* on [English.SE] and so far the only answer supports my use as valid.

Comment: hmmm... I am not really qualified to judge on that. Still, if something is broken, it must have been whole at some point, no? Adding to dysfunctional (which I like because it sounds like something is seriously wrong) I would propose *kaput* (or correctly *kaputt*) to add some polyglot spice.

Comment: "Functionality," if untaken perhaps.  Bit generic, though.

Answer (score 3):

[tom-sawyer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tom-sawyer) No, requires user to be familiar with American literature.

[have-no-clue](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/have-no-clue) No, they too often think they do.

[houston-we-have-a-problem](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/houston-we-have-a-problem) Famous (incorrect) quote but the meaning is clear.

[matematica-hates-me](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/matematica-hates-me) Might work.

[arrrrrrrrrgh](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arrrrrrrrrgh) Peanut's Charlie Brown's cry of frustration

[whats-going-wrong-here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/whats-going-wrong-here) Semi-serious proposal.

We have a [recent post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/29740/) right now where the poster used [plotting](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plotting) and [replacement](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/replacement), neither of which was relevant to his real problem.

#### Edit

Inspired by this Meta topic, I added [infinite-loop](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/infinite-loop). Might help with some of the questions in the class Mr.Wizard is concerned with.

Comment: I think it's a given that the question won't start out tagged appropriately.  The question becomes what do we *re*-tag it with?

Comment: I took the freedom to add another *fun tag* to your list

Comment: Buggrit, millennium hand and shrimp!

Comment: Or, [tag:fishing].